# How to know when we exited a roundabout when using Google Map API - Directions API

Tags: google-maps, mapbox, directions

Im using Google Map API with Directions API to get routes that show instructions to users while driving.

Before they arrive to a round about, I can tell them the take the "n th" exit. But when they are in the round about, the google api thinks we are at the next step and is saying something like turn right in 500m. So, I want to know when we exited a roundabout before showing the next step instruction.

I am aware that with Mapbox API direction we can have intersections but is there a way to have this info with Google API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware of restrictions exposed in the Terms of Service. Please look at paragraph 10.4 (c) that says

> No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

Your use case might be a violation of ToS.